# IEnumerable as Out Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to write a method, that would give, top 10 records and also total no. of records, from the table. Unable to figure out how to access the output parameters.
It gives an error - Using the generic type IEnumerable requires 1 type argument.
Please do Suggest if there is a better way.

DAL:

```
public void GetData(out IEnumerable<tblCountry> iList, out int rowCount)
{    
  iList = DBContext.tblCountries.Where(c=>c.Id > 0).Take(10);    
  rowCount = DBContext.tblCountries.Where(c=>c.Id > 0).Count();    
}
```

BLL:

```
public void GetData(out IEnumerable<tblCountry> iList, out int rowCount)
{    
  objDAL.GetData(out iList, out rowCount);    
}
```

Code Behind:

```
objBLL.(out IEnumerable<tblCountry> iList, out int rowCount);//Error here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code behind you should first declare the 2 variables and then pass them as `out` parameters to the GetData method:

```
IEnumerable<tblCountry> iList;
int rowCount;
objBLL.GetData(out iList, out rowCount);
```

As an alternative approach you could design a model that will represent the result of this operation and having the method return this model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<tblCountry> Countries { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public MyModel GetData()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.Countries = DBContext.tblCountries.Where(c=>c.Id > 0).Take(10);
    model.RowCount = DBContext.tblCountries.Where(c=>c.Id > 0).Count();
    return model;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
MyModel model = objBLL.GetData();
// here you could use model.Countries and model.RowCount
```